# Remove all items from array using Reducer - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Below is the structure of my reducer that i used to remove items from my array (cart). In the code below, i am only able to remove a `single item` at a time. How do i remove all items on the cart when i click on the remove button or icon which triggers the reducer ?

PS: Beginner with React

**Reducer.JS**

```
export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ON_DELETE_ITEM_FROM_CART:
            let index = state.cart.indexOf(action.payload)
            return update(state, {
                cart: {
                    $splice: [[index, 1]]
                }
            });
   }
```

Comment: why not assigning an empty array cart = `[]`?

Comment: @DennisVash, in the reducer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ON_DELETE_ALL_ITEMS_FROM_CART:
            return update(state, { cart: [] });
   }
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of *why* and *how* it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

here you can empty your full cart code from my reducer

```
   const initialState = {
  items: {},
  totalAmount: 0,
};
const cartItems = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {


case CLEAR_CART:
        
          return  state={ items: {}, totalAmount: 0, }
```